# Miniconda installation error on Linux and aarch64

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, arm64, miniconda

I’m trying to install Miniconda on a debian linux, running on Arm Cortex A-53.
I’ve downloaded `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh`, and now trying to install using

```bash
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

Getting the following error:

```bash
[/home/analog/miniconda3] >>>
PREFIX=/home/analog/miniconda3
Unpacking payload …
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 406: /home/analog/miniconda3/conda.exe: No such file or directory
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 409: /home/analog/miniconda3/preconda.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?
It’s strange that there is a conda.exe involved on a linux…

#### Additional Info

- Tried running as `root` - same behavior.
- Trying to install full Anaconda - same behavior.

Sanity Check:
Running `uname -m` returns "aarch64"

Checking the created directory with `ls -l` confirms that there *is* a `conda.exe` file present there.

Comment: My guess is that you're running a 32-bit userland on a 64-bit kernel. What does `file /bin/bash` print?

Comment: Have you checked that the system satisfies all [the system requirements](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#system-requirements) (note that `linux-aarch64` is more constrained)? Maybe try installing [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) instead, as they tend to have broader kernel support (but still need actual 64-bit OS on `aarch64` hardware).

Comment: Thank you both, seems that the OS is indeed 32-bit